# Vagrant error: NFS is reporting that your exports file is invalid

Tags: export, vagrant, nfs, discourse

I am trying to set up the Discourse development environment using these [instructions](http://blog.discourse.org/2013/04/discourse-as-your-first-rails-app/). However when I run Vagrant I get the error:

> NFS is reporting that your exports file is invalid. Vagrant does
>   this check before making any changes to the file. Please correct
>   the issues below and execute "vagrant reload":
>
> Can't open /etc/exports

I checked, and I don't have an etc/exports folder, so I created one and ran `vagrant reload`. This got me:

> /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/hosts/bsd/host.rb:146:in `read': Is a directory - /etc/exports (Errno::EISDIR)
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/hosts/bsd/host.rb:146:in`nfs_prune'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/synced_folders/nfs/synced_folder.rb:68:in `cleanup'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folder_cleanup.rb:24:in`block in call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folder_cleanup.rb:22:in `each_key'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folder_cleanup.rb:22:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_nfs_valid_ids.rb:12:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:118:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_forwarded_port_collision_params.rb:30:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:52:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:13:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:19:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in`block in finalize_action'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in`block in run'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in`run'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:51:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in`busy'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `run'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:51:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in`block in finalize_action'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in`block in run'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in`run'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:51:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:57:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in`busy'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `run'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:51:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in`call'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in`busy'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `run'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:147:in`action'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/commands/reload/command.rb:37:in `block in execute'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:193:in`block in with_target_vms'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:191:in `each'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:191:in`with_target_vms'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/commands/reload/command.rb:36:in `execute'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:38:in`execute'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:484:in `cli'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/bin/vagrant:127:in`'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/bin/vagrant:23:in `load'
>       from /Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/bin/vagrant:23:in`'

I am on a Mac (OS X 10.6.8). How do I fix this? I tried searching for the original error message, and all I found was a few repositories containing the Vagrant source code that throws it.

Answer (score -33, accepted):

Try using the known good versions of VirtualBox and Vagrant noted in *[Discourse as Your First Rails App](http://blog.discourse.org/2013/04/discourse-as-your-first-rails-app/)*:

- [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html) 1.1.2
- [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) 4.2.10

I was having the same issue on Mac (OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)), but rolling back to these versions seemed to fix it for me.

Comment: Thanks I'm still finishing the next installation steps, but it looks like that worked.

Comment: Downgrading is not required. You just need to run `sudo touch /etc/exports`. See [colinhoernig's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20750058/134014). Also, I just updated my vagrant install to v1.4.3 and VirtualBox to v4.3.8 and that seemed to solve my problem.

Comment: this is a misleading answer. please select the colinhoemig's answer as its much more helpful!

Comment: The answer is not constructive and missleading. I wonder how it is marked as correct. The correct answer is that of @colinhoernig that has been voted up more than 50 times. 

For the Error to be  resolved. You need to fix the /etc/exports file. Then build again.

Comment: When you're building a project with documented dependencies for the first time it helps to use the exact versions that are known to work, just because there's a work around for this one exact issue doesn't mean he wouldn't run into other undocumented incompatibilities...

Comment: It's been a long time, but still, you are my savior @Donut.

Answer (score 336):

I had some previous images/boxes installed in my VirtualBox installation, so there were a few invalid entries in `/etc/exports` already. So I had to clean up that file and restart my Vagrant box.

```
NFS is reporting that your exports file is invalid. Vagrant does
this check before making any changes to the file. Please correct
the issues below and execute "vagrant reload":
```

Here's what I did on my host machine:

```
sudo rm /etc/exports
sudo touch /etc/exports

vagrant halt
vagrant up --provision
```

Comment: This was the most applicable one, as I had two vagrant boxes mounting the same folder.  They got confused!

Comment: or instead of delete all, just remove all those lines related to those VM's that are not anymore there.

Comment: I had this issue after renaming the project dir name. Thanks! :)

Comment: or you can just simply edit the file with correct path

Comment: This worked for me too.  But I did get an error saying Vagrant could not read the exports file due to a permissions error.  I had to run:

sudo chmod 655 /etc/exports

Then it worked.

Comment: It can be worth to mention that this command should be executed on host machine. Because by vagrant box is actually booted, I could log in to it, but couldn't find /etc/exports file. Because it is on host machine.

Comment: Instead of deleting the whole file you can just edit it and remove old unused paths

Comment: This issue held me back, I had very old files from my early days testing in IE6 using virtual machines.

Comment: Additional step of "restart machine" after vagrant halt was required for me

Comment: I'm not sure that the `--provision` flag is necessary in the last command, as typically NFS is mounted on `up` rather than at provisioning time. It may be required in your setup, but these steps worked for me without that flag.

Comment: This fixed it for me. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: -- provision is not necessary and depending on what it does for you it can even be dangerous (i.e. import some starting database over most recent one). Instead, do just what vagrant says you should do: 'Please correct
the issues below and execute "vagrant reload"'. For "correct the issue" do first 2 lines @totas suggested here.

Answer (score 79):

I ran into this issue with Vagrant 1.4.1 and VirtualBox 4.3.6 on OS X 10.9 Mavericks (13A603).  I was able to fix it with a simple command to create the missing /etc/exports file.  Run this on OS X, not guest, as pointed out in comments below.

```
$ sudo touch /etc/exports
```

I was then able to successfully run `vagrant up`.  I did run into another error where the Guest Additions weren't up to date, but I fixed that issue by installing the vagrant-vbguest plugin.

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
```

and then a quick `vagrant reload` and I was up and running!

Comment: I had to use sudo rm -rf /etc/exports on linux as it is a folder

Comment: I also had to edit my /etc/exports file because it had multiple entries that was confusing vagrant.

Comment: I had to delete the contents of my exports file

Answer (score 23):

For me, this error started appearing for a working Vagrant environment.

I had renamed the directory Vagrant was running from. To fix it, I ran 'sudo vi /etc/exports' and fixed the pathname so it pointed to my current directory.

Answer (score 9):

The same thing happened to me. I copied over my Vagrantfile from another project and forgot to change the NFS settings. This caused the current VM to mount the parent folder of the VM that I copied the original Vagrantfile from. So I did this:

```
vagrant halt
vagrant up
```

Still got the same error. So I tracked down my exports file located at */etc/exports* which looks like this:

```
# VAGRANT-BEGIN: 501 64e10d4d-342e-4f55-b69a-97edda35742f
"/Users/[username]/vagrant" 192.168.11.12 -alldirs -mapall=501:20
# VAGRANT-END: 501 64e10d4d-342e-4f55-b69a-97edda35742f
# VAGRANT-BEGIN: 501 b3c6e7fe-95d4-48db-8876-c89d3e07af8d
"/Users/[username]/Sites/molitech-oms" 192.168.11.124 -alldirs -mapall=501:20
# VAGRANT-END: 501 b3c6e7fe-95d4-48db-8876-c89d3e07af8d
# VAGRANT-BEGIN: 501 3e2aabfd-ce63-441b-85a2-1b51e8beb863
"/Users/[username]/Sites/app" 192.168.11.125 -alldirs -mapall=501:20
# VAGRANT-END: 501 3e2aabfd-ce63-441b-85a2-1b51e8beb863
# VAGRANT-BEGIN: 501 ff92e353-9f6d-48ee-9d76-e29b33f1dd60
"/Users/[username]/Sites" 192.168.11.126 -alldirs -mapall=501:20
# VAGRANT-END: 501 ff92e353-9f6d-48ee-9d76-e29b33f1dd60
```

The last two paths are the same. So I deleted the last three lines and ran:

```
vagrant halt && vagrant up
```

Now everything seems to be working fine.

OSX 10.11.1
Vagrant 1.7.4

Answer (score 8):

I didn't want to go through the hassle of downgrading. This is what I did (still took a while, but less hassle than downgrading IMHO):

1. In the VM Vagrantfile, for any synced folder, disabled NFS

   `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", nfs: false`
2. Removed /etc/exports

   `sudo mv /etc/exports ~/Desktop/exports`
3. Rewrite /etc/exports

   `vagrant up`
4. Re-enable NFS if you want/need it enabled on your VM

   `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", nfs: true`

Answer (score 6):

Just run following commands:

```
sudo rm /etc/exports
sudo touch /etc/exports
vagrant reload
```

Do **NOT** use `vagrant up --provision` if you are not sure that it won't overwrite current status of your project.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 12 host/Ubuntu 12 guest the following worked for me with [Discourse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_(software)):

```
nfs_setting = RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/ || RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /linux/
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", id: "vagrant-root", type: "nfs", nfs_udp: "true", nfs_version: "4", :nfs => nfs_setting
```

Note: I also had to add a host IP address determined by Vagrant and guest IP address determined by Vagrant to firewall exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

i ran `vagrant box list` this showed me that there were 4 vagrant boxes (must have accidentally created them at some point - i usually only use one. So then I ran `vagrant box prune` , which deleted my unused boxes. then `vagrant up` started working again!