# Vagrant path issue

Tags: vagrant

I am new to vagrant and have created a machine.

When I do a vagrant up I am getting the following error:

> ```
> NFS is reporting that your exports file is invalid. Vagrant does this   
> check before making any changes to the file. Please correct
> the issues below and execute "vagrant reload":
> ```
>
> exports:23: path contains non-directory or non-existent components:
>
> /Path/To/vagrant/manifests

I understand the path is incorrect, but how and where do I update it to the correct path?

Comment: its probably somewhere in your Vagrantfile, can you show the Vagrantfile ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vagrant error: NFS is reporting that your exports file is invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20726248/vagrant-error-nfs-is-reporting-that-your-exports-file-is-invalid)

Comment: delete `etc/exports` and `sudo touch etc/exports`

Comment: Any idea where I change this: /Path/To/vagrant/manifests At present it is looking for manifests in an old machine that no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

Remove /etc/exports and recreate the exports file again.

```
sudo rm /etc/exports
sudo touch /etc/exports

vagrant halt
vagrant up
```

The solution has taken from: https://gist.github.com/ikennaokpala/79f033880ecd38272a411350c6d573c0

Comment: That worked just fine for me, just for general knowledge on MacOs (Mojave) the exports file is in `/private/etc/exports`